# WCF service not returning JSONP which causes error in dojo app

Tags: dojo, jsonp

I have tried many demos and egs. and finally got some good advice here when I was having issues with service requests. Anyway I am using io.script.get to get data from a remote server and the problem is that the callback parameter is either undefined or sometimes I get an invalid label.

```
function searchGoogle() {
    // Look up the node we'll stick the text under.
    var targetNode = dojo.byId("rules");
    var jsonpArgs = {
  url: "http://localhost/WcfServices/WcfInstanceRules2/Service1.svc/RetrieveData",
     callbackParamName: "callback",
       content: {
            screenName: "dpjo"
        },
        load: function (data) {
            // Set the data from the search into the viewbox in nicely formatted JSON
            targetNode.innerHTML = "<pre>" + dojo.toJson(data, true) + "</pre>";
        },
        error: function (error) {
            targetNode.innerHTML = "An unexpected error occurred: " + error;
        }
    };
    dojo.io.script.get(jsonpArgs);
}
dojo.ready(searchGoogle);
```

I see the json response in fiddler and it looks fine but in the browser I will get an error. This is frustrating because I have been struggling with cross domain issues. I am using .net 4.0 and do no have to explicitly define callback. I tried manually editing the json response by adding the callback name and wrapping the json in the callback name.

EDIT:

Sample of data returned from webservice:

```
{"rules":[{"value":"AllState"},{"value":"Cidade de Goa beach"},
     {"value":"Euro 2012"},{"value":"Euro&2012"},
     {"value":"Euro2012"},  {"value":"European&Championship"},
     {"value":"Holiday Inn Resort"},{"value":"Holiday Inn Resort goa"},
     {"value":"Hotel Goa"},{"value":"Hyatt Goa"},{"value":"I buy car}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its got to be a problem on the server.  Can you try pointing at some known working service (like Yahoo.com), just for a quick test?

Comment: do you think its the server or the actual web service hosted on that server

Comment: The web service hosted there.  I think there's something not right in the data being returned.  Maybe post an example of the service response in your question.